How is it possible that rpy2 is altering the values within my dataframe?
I am trying to utilize some R based packages within a Python script using the rpy2 package. In order to implement the code, I first need to convert a Pandas dataframe into an R based data matrix. However, something incredibly strange is happening to the values within the code. Here is a minimally reproducible example of the code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()

utils = importr('utils')

# Function to generate random column names
def generate_column_names(n, suffixes):
    columns = []
    for _ in range(n):
        name = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=3))  # Random 3-character string
        suffix = random.choice(suffixes)  # Randomly choose between "_Healthy" and "_Sick"
        columns.append(name + suffix)
    return columns
    
# Number of rows and columns
n_rows = 1000
n_cols = 15

# Generate random float values between 0 and 10
data = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(n_rows, n_cols))

# Introduce NaN values sporadically
nan_indices = np.random.choice([True, False], size=data.shape, p=[0.1, 0.9])
data[nan_indices] = np.nan

# Generate random column names
column_names = generate_column_names(n_cols, ["_Healthy", "_Sick"])


# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)

df = df.replace(np.nan, "NA")


with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
     R_df = ro.conversion.py2rpy(df)

r_matrix = r('data.matrix')(R_df)

Now, the input Pandas dataframe looks like this:

However, after turning it into a R based dataframe using ro.conversion.py2rpy(), and then recasting that as a data matrix using r('data.matrix'), I get a r_matrix dataframe that look like this:

How could this happen? I have checked the intermediate R_df and have found that it has the same values as the input Pandas df, so it seems that the line r('data.matrix') is drastically altering my contents.
I have run the analogous commands in R (after importing the exact same dataframe into R using readr), and data.matrix does not affect my dataframe's contents at all, so I am incredibly confused as to what the problem is. Has anyone else experienced this at all?

Your column is being coerced to a factor and then numeric
When in Python you do df = df.replace(np.nan, "NA"), you are replacing with the literal string "NA". That means that the "NA" values are then stored as an object rather than float64.
Unlike pandas, R does not have an object type. Columns (or vectors in R) need to all be the same type. If a vector contains numeric and string values, R ultimately treats the whole thing as character.
The behaviour that you get with a character vector using data.matrix() is:

Character columns are first converted to factors and then to integers.

For example:
set.seed(1)
(df <- data.frame(
    x = 1:5,
    y = (as.character(rnorm(5)))
))

#   x                  y
# 1 1 -0.626453810742332
# 2 2  0.183643324222082
# 3 3 -0.835628612410047
# 4 4   1.59528080213779
# 5 5   0.32950777181536

data.matrix(df)

#      x y
# [1,] 1 1
# [2,] 2 3
# [3,] 3 2
# [4,] 4 5
# [5,] 5 4

Use NA_real_
There is a class rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NARealType. You need to instantiate this and then replace np.nan with this object. This means the entire column can remain a float64 in Python, and numeric in R, so there is no coercion to factor.
na = rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NARealType()

df2 = df.replace(np.nan, na)

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
     R_df = ro.conversion.py2rpy(df2)


r_matrix = ro.r('data.matrix')(R_df)
r_matrix

Output:
array([[6.71551482, 3.37235768, 1.73878498, ..., 9.26968137, 4.44605036,
        0.57638575],
       [2.14651571, 5.14706755, 7.43517449, ..., 7.56905516, 3.1960465 ,
        9.13240441],
       [0.67569123, 8.55601696, 3.34151056, ...,        nan, 4.12252086,
        5.79825217],
       ...,
       [2.93515376, 2.29766304, 2.70761156, ..., 7.80345898, 0.34809462,
        4.5128469 ],
       [5.66194126, 1.32135235, 2.57649142, ..., 3.49908635, 3.77794316,
        8.96322655],
       [8.43950172, 1.65306388, 7.37031975, ..., 8.01045219, 8.68857319,
        7.51309124]])


That's a really good point! Sadly, the package I want to use does not take in NaN values, it only works with NA values. And because of how my input data will be set up, there will be missing values occurring. If I remove the the line df = df.replace(np.nan, "NA"), then the R based package I want to use will not work. Which begs the question, how best should I approach the problem at hand Should I try to replace the NaN values after converting the pandas df into an R based df? Or can I recast them somehow?

@BobMcBobson I've never really used rpy2 but I'm sure there's a way to do it. What about if you replace np.nan with pd.NA? Or with None?

Try replacing with NA rather than the character string "NA"

@BobMcBobson looking at the docs, you might want to try df = df.replace(np.nan, rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NARealType). Let me know if this works - otherwise a little later I may try and install these packages and test it myself.

@SamR I tried, sadly it did not work. I have tried also replacing the np.nan with robjects.NA_Real as per the documents, and that also did not work. It seems like I might need to replace the np.nan values in between R_df and r_matrix, but I have no idea how to.

@SamR looking at the documentation of rpy2 (https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#robjects-missingvalues), there seems to be a special way to handle NAs, but it's not clear what I must do next.

@AndrewGustar this approach only yields an error as NA is not defined in my code.

@BobMcBobson I downloaded the packages and seem to have cracked it now - see my edit

@SamR thank you, your approach was correct, as r_matrix = r('data.matrix')(R_df) now retains the same values as R_df. Sadly, I am still not getting what I need, because the R package I am trying to implement is being quite difficult to use through the rpy2 interface. I will post another question here to try to figure out how to fix this.

@BobMcBobson in your new question I think it would be good to give quite a bit of context about what you're trying to do and whether you're open to a non rpy2 option. I use R and Python a lot and I've never used rpy2 or reticulate. I see so many questions about problems with the interface between the two and, at least for the kinds of tasks I'm doing, it's always easier to just save the data to disk in a Python script and then open it in an R script, or vice versa.

@SamR yeah that's actually a pretty good idea... I can get my R based package to work fine in a normal R script and environment, so it might be prudent to stop trying to use rpy2 and try a different approach
